# How could entropy control go wrong?

Tags: science-based, magic, physics, balancing-magic-systems

The magic system of my story works by either increasing or decreasing entropy with the decrease requiring a specific spot ex. dust collecting into a concentrated point or the increase requiring an area ex. water expanding into a fine mist in a 1 meter sphere. They are at a roughly ~1410s level of technology. Energy required scales with effect but can use technology to make things easier. Only around 10% of the population can use magic and only very few are any good at it. How could they abuse this? I'll try to make rules to combat any abuses.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have no idea why you would think that "dust collecting into a concentrated spot" is a good example of increasing or decreasing entropy: first, entropy of what exactly? and second, how do you define the entropy of that physical system, whatever it is? And then, dust collecting into a concentrated spot is what a housewife does when she sweeps the floor with her broom, so I don't see why you believe that magic is required or even useful for collecting the dust into a dustpan.

Comment: The entropy of the local system, in that example, concentration like going from bits of dust spread over an entire surface to only one spot retaining all the mass that was there but now smaller in area, yes it is simple but it is only meant to be a simple example of what you could do, you could for example change the temperature of someone's brain till they die.

Comment: this sounds like a brainstorming question, which is off topic.

Comment: Should I delete the post then?

Comment: Asking us to think up ways a system of rules can be abused is not a suitable question for this site. Depending on how you define abuse, there could be any number of valid answers. We have a requirement on this site that you ask a singular specific question not seek  general commentary or review.

Comment: You can't delete your question anymore because it received an answer. You could make your question more specific, but be careful not to invalidate that existing answer. You can use [Help] or [How to ask good questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as guides. On our Meta site there is also a [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to get direct feedback on your question.

Comment: Does the user of entropy control seem to others as just extremely lucky or are they actively altering these situations in a way that is visible?
Do we have any limits to work within? 
I've given an answer, but as others have mentioned, it's a bit open ended at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'll have to VTC this question. While entropy control as a concept seems really interesting, as-is this question isn't a good fit for the site and it is unlike we'll be able to help you. If you can focus it more, with more clear rules of how your system works, we may be able to salvage the question and re-open it, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### IRL Entropy = Order vs Chaos (with a natural lean toward chaos)

In a nutshell, the line dividing the two is as such.

- During an earthquake, a house may crumble into a pile of bricks, wood, dust, and what ever items were in the house prior to the quake. (Order moves toward chaos per laws of nature)
- While it is within the realm of possibility to have a random pile of the same materials shake their way into a fully formed house, filled with populated bookshelves after being exposed to an earthquake, that likelihood is so low that it's practically impossible. (Chaos does not move toward order typically without some very specific forces applied to the system, which often also create chaos through heat etc)

This is in essence part of the relationship of cause and effect as well.

- A house + earthquake = pile of rubble.
- A pile of rubble + earthquake = a more mangled, more spread out pile of rubble.

I think we have more of a scope problem to solve, as to what exactly we're attempting to Control.

We could have an Entropy control potential anywhere from shaking your feet to have your shoes tie themselves, to cause and effect reversed to where we have a "Tenet" scenario.

A runaway scenario at it's worse would be the reversal of universal expansion, through a reversal of cause/effect or natural passage toward chaos being toward order instead, effectively reverses time until the big bang is undone.

This gives a large window of potential for someone meddling with the tides of chaos going wrong.

- Another answer mentions MAGE the ascension, which uses magic Spheres to define what a magic user can or cannot do (read: should not do) as well as the sort of backlash possible for breaking the rules anyway. (Time is a separate magic sphere to note)
- Mage limits what the Sphere of Entropy can do, usually affecting the RNG of every day life. Examples being, Someone is about to shoot a gun, but by chance it ends up jamming or being dud, a bullet badly made at the factory. You are late to a job interview but by chance the building was having some power issues that reset all their clocks about 10 minutes ago and no one notices. You can alter the likelihood of cancer developing or spontaneously curing itself. Is someone drops a delicate glass sculpture, you can potentially have it land in just the right way to prevent it's shattering.

#### Define "Entropy control" as being able to affect the outcomes of probability, but while staying within the realm of possible and many of the universe ending threats vanish.

This sort of limitation I think is what needs defined. Are we affecting the universe's definition of entropy, or are we simply pressing a finger on the scales of chance?

- We cannot have an earthquake build a house out of rubble, buuuut perhaps the house was constructed during a time where the owner was worried about earthquakes long ago, to where you just lucked out in having the only house still standing on your block due to an otherwise unexpected reason for that to be possible being revealed. Perhaps a fault line lies right across the street and the side where your house is was completely unaffected by the Earthquake.
- You may be able to use your entropic powers to sense the upcoming earthquake ahead of time as a sort of magical sense, your mind sensing all the potential for chaos to ensue, for now resting on the peak of potential, that final push needed to set of the chain of events almost felt like a pressure of sorts when ever you are in the area.

The exact facilitation of how one would create these effects may also give us hints as to the limitations of these powers:

- Can they simply think of the car chasing them hitting a patch of ice and it happens?
- Do they need to study the system to know where to place their hand on the scales of chance at the right time?
- Do they need to directly see what potentials exist and they can simply follow the course of action that leads to their preferred outcomes?

It's a potential with much potential for things to go wrong, but so far, we're not sure how right things can go either.

Less severe entropy botches: Look at the Wild Magic table from DnD 5E for examples of random effects appearing alongside intended affects.

- example: I want to affect how the random light bounces off my face to make myself look like someone else, but whoops person's face is also blue for the duration, light bends a teeny differently than I intended.
- example: I tried to create a spontaneous combustion to set the contents of a trashcan on fire to make a distraction, but added too much chaos to where it doesn't ignite a flame, but also explodes because someone tossed away an aerosol can earlier.

Specific examples from the 1400s:

- Entropic explosion, when water evaporates to steam, the resulting steam takes 1600 times the volume of the water it used to be. Water molecules depending on their entropy lie in an orderly crystal matrix (solid), free swimming but still locally grouped (liquid), or flying freely to fill their entire volume (steam).
- Disintegration, imbue a living being with enough entropy and it's biological processes become chaotic enough their DNA essentially forgets how to properly go through mitosis, now actively falling apart over time instead of healing.
- Inanimate immortality, by removing the entropic effects of the passage of time (by funneling it into another target item or finding a way to halt them entirely) an item can be made immune to the natural decay of daily use, by making the item somewhat self repairing during use. More useful for delicate and repeated/constant use items (industrial parts/systems) than personal use items as daily wear and tear is not the same as resisting intents to destroy (in the case of attempting to make impenetrable armor, entropy is not the only force working to unmake it).
- Growth speed effects of a crop, by increasing the entropic force within a field crop, you can alter the rate of growth. Example: Strawberry taste is a matter of growth time, with stronger tastes emerging the longer the berry takes to grow, some growers moved up to cold mountains to slow the speed of growth. You could selectively do the same, slowing or speeding the changes of a growing crop to a noticeable extent. Trying to push the boundaries of biological processes may have unexpected results though. You can cut 20% off the growth time of a crop; trying to grow a freshly planted field overnight however, usually ends up with growths that hardly resemble their target crop. Some crops increase in size over time, allowing you to obtain a higher yield, assuming you account for the extra resources the plant will require in order to keep up it's new growth speed.

Comment: "A runaway scenario at it's worse would be the reversal of universal expansion, through a reversal of cause/effect or natural passage toward chaos being toward order instead, effectively reverses time until the big bang is undone." This is actually the in lore reason for why it was invented in the first place, as a civilization's last ditch attempt against the heat-death of the universe, of course that large of an effect is beyond the civilization's power at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

There are some limitations that nature imposes us which, if broken, break reality as we understand it. Usually it's the speed of light: people want faster than light speeds, but hate it when that necessarily causes causality to break and every trip involves time travel.

With entropy, you get something even worse: if you break the second law of thermodynamics, the best case scenario is that you allow for perpetual motion machines. But if you can make even a single process that is 100.[as many zeroes as you want here]1% efficient, then you open multiple doors to time travel, negative energy and infinite energy. The latter can obliterate anything from the magic user to the visible universe, depending on how you apply it.

We've exploited this kind of magic in other questions, and infinite energy generation pops up here and there. If you want to avoid this, then focus on this part where you said:

> Energy required scales with effect (...)

And make sure that the energy required for any effect is greater than the energy you take out from it, i.e.: evaporating water takes more energy than what that water would grant you if condensed and thrown into a water mill.

But once you do this, what you have is no longer entropy manipulation. You will end up with some sophisticated system of telekinesis instead, which is something else.

Entropy magic is better applied to statistical things, or matter of chance (and therefore luck). You could get some inspiration from the tabletop RPG Mage: the Ascension, in which whole groups of mages study this kind of magic.

From [one of that game's fandom wikis](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Entropy_(MTAs))

> Determinism and chaos are equal partners to the student. The mage can spot chance on the move, recognizing points where probability quirks in odd directions. An Entropy-schooled mage can manipulate random factors, observe and influence flaws within a system, induce or remove corruption, and otherwise exert their Will through the inexorable process of mortality.

And some sample applications:

> Sense Fate and Fortune: The mage can sense shifts in probability and spot flaws in Patterns.

> Control Probability: The mage can influence Patterns with Entropic energy, which allows them to control the outcome of simple events (like altering a dice throw).

> Affect Predictable Patterns: The mage can directly affect inanimate Patterns of varying complexity, controlling the speed at which material objects fail or decay.

Etc., etc.

By the way, of all the spheres of magic in that game, Entropy just happens to be my favorite :)

Comment: Do you think that a medieval society would be able to take advantage of a 100.0001% efficiency tho?

Comment: @NovusPendragon of course they would. If it's cheaper to pay a mage to levitate bricks rather than pay a team of carpenters and stonemasons, the mage gets the job. By the way, modern ICE engines are 27% efficient at best. A 100.0001% efficient mage is four times better than a 2023 gasoline engine.

Comment: Recently turned on to MAGE, very much a fan of the system, though it is interesting how they separate Entropy and Time, which otherwise I would have assumed were much more closely tied together. Such an open and complex system, yet well enough defined to be useful in answering magical system questions that arean't MAGE related